# How to initialize tab content when app is initialized

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I have an app that has 2 tabs. Each tab loads an xml file (fairly large, maybe 400 item rss file).

By default the tab doesn't get the xml until it's clicked on. I simply wanted a way to load it all when the app is first opened.

Here is the main view:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Audio Feed
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AudioFeed.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("audio").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_audio))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    // Video Feed
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, VideoFeed.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("video").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_video))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); //todo: remember what tab user was last on
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use TabHost.setCurrentTab(x) or TabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(x).

```
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

For Initialization I use [TabHost.OnTabChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html).

```
private OnTabChangeListener mOnTabChangeListener = new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        if (FBIntent.EXTRA_XX.equals(tag)) {
            // Current tab is xx.
            ... if xx not init -> ...
        } else if (FBIntent.EXTRA_YY.equals(tag)) {
            // Current tab is yy.
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: ah nice hack with the `setCurrentTab` method. I used that and now its golden. Thanks user802421

Answer (score 1):

In this same method do whats the other tabs do. I mean what the other do when you click them. So you have the same thing for all tabs. Don't forget to include this same tab in the `OnTabChanged()` method and do the same operations again, otherwise you'll get nothing when this tab is clicked again.